# EncodedImage create(String i) explanation

Tags: codenameone

I would need an explanation of the following method, placed in `EncodedImage.java`:

```
    /**
     * Creates an image from the input stream 
     * 
     * @param i the resource
     * @return newly created encoded image
     * @throws java.io.IOException if thrown by the input stream
     */
    public static EncodedImage create(String i) throws IOException {
        return create(Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(EncodedImage.class, i));
    }
```

I have doubts about what the string passed as the argument is, I suppose that the Javadoc is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Java resource i.e file in the jar. So if you have in your src root "image.png" then `/image.png` should work.

The "image from input stream" is a copy/paste error but effectively that's what happens under the hood.